# Requesting access to Real-time API beta not owner of project

Tags: google-analytics-api

I have access to this Google Analytics data:

[image]

I haven't created this project; I can merely view the data.

Now, I want to leverage [Google Analytics Real time API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) to get this number "`952`".

When I go to Googles documentation, I'm told I need to sign up for beta access the API asking me some project number?

[image]

Now when I open https://console.cloud.google.com/ I can only see the projects that I have created; not the ones I have access to.

How do I go forward from here?

If there is no way out.. What do I need to tell the owner of the original project so that he/she can grant me API level access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only the owner of the project on [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/projects?authuser=0) can apply for beta access or make any changes to the project itself.

You are going to have to ask them to make you an owner as well or ask them to apply for the beta access.

Note: Once you apply it normally takes around 24 hours to get access you wont hear from Google.  Just try it see if it works.